# useTabController index never changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I am using hooks for handling tab controller, the problem is when i print the current index of the controller it is right. But when i try to display it inside a text widget it is never changes! how could i use it?

**The code is:**

```
class TabBarDemo extends HookWidget {
  final List<Widget> list = const [
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _controller =
        useTabController(initialLength: list.length, initialIndex: 0);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      print("\n ${_controller.index} \n");
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          onTap: (index) {},
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: list,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(
            '${_controller.index}',
          )),
          Center(
              child: Text(
            '${_controller.index}',
          )),
          Center(
              child: Text(
            '${_controller.index}',
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is because you need to rebuild your `Text` widget every time `index` changes - in most cases it is done by calling `State.setState` method (i see you are using 3rd party `HookWidget` so it can have its own rebuild methods)

Comment: make it as an answer to accept it, please.

Comment: ok i looked at `HookWidget` and instead of `_controller.addListener` you need: `final _controller = useTabController(initialLength: ...); useListenable(_controller);` - now you are adding a listener multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rebuild the tree using :
setState(() {
});

Answer (score -1):

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabController = useTabController(initialLength: 2);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
          toolbarHeight: 72.h,
          title: const Text(
            'Alert one time',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 22),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.imageAlertsSettingsIcon),
            ),
          ],
          elevation: 0,
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            dividerColor: Colors.white10,
            tabs: listAlerts.map((String item) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [AlertsPercentPage(), AlertsPricePage()]));
  }
```

That's how it works for me

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**